# 'function' object has no attribute 'layers'

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, keras

```
from change_mask import change_circle
import numpy as np

def new_mask_update(re_diagnosis_model,  mask_layer_activated, new_mask, times):
   
    weight_s = [re_diagnosis_model.layers[i].get_weights() for i in mask_layer_activated]
    newmask_copy = [np.abs(weight_s[i][0].copy()*new_mask[i].copy()) for i in range(len(weight_s))]
 
    new_mask = change_circle(newmask_copy,times+1,N=10,spmax=1,spmin=0.5)

    for i in range(len(mask_layer_activated)):
        weight_s[i][0] *= new_mask[i]
    return new_mask, weight_s
```

line4,'function' object has no attribute 'layers'

Comment: Hey @gaoyue, welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep in mind that this website is for English questions and answers only. Also, when asking a question, please describe the intention and the problem you are encountering. Just code snippets are not enough to determine what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you meant `re_diagnosis_model().layers[i].get_weights()`. It's impossible to tell because you didn't post enough code to determine what `re_diagnosis_model` does.